# Como colocar um submenu, em um menu que eu já tenho?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Eu estou editando o blog, e eu queria fazer um menu com submenus, mas eu não sei exatamente o que faz isso acontecer. Eu tentei pesquisar no google mas não consegui nada. 
Só aparecem tutoriais de css, mas nada especifico que possa me dizer qual código de css faz aquilo. Eu quero saber exatamente o que faz um menu ficar com um submenu... javascript, css, jquery.. Qualquer coisa...

Eu estou usando este código, que funciona muito bem... 
http://tableless.com.br/header-responsivo-somente-com-css/

Só que eu quero colocar um submenu nele. Como está a seguir:

```css
header {
  min-height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #ECECEC;
  z-index: 2;
}

header ul {
  padding: 15px 10px 0 0;
}

header li {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

header li:first-child {
  border: none;
}

header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

header li a:hover {
  color: #333;
}
header > ul > li > ul{
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
-moz-opacity: 0.00;
opacity: 0.00;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=0);
}
 
header > ul > li:hover > ul{
-moz-opacity: 1;
opacity: 1;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=100);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  header .control-nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border: solid #333;
    border-width: 3px 0;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  header .control-nav:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    background: #333;
  }
  header .control-nav-close {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
    -webkit-transform: translate(100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(100%, 0);
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
  }
  header nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 250px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
    overflow-x: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
    -webkit-transform: translate(100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(100%, 0);
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
  }
}

#control-nav:checked ~ .control-nav-close {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

#control-nav:checked ~ nav {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<header>
  <h1 class="fL">
    <a href="#" title="">Teste</a>
  </h1>

  <nav class="fR">
    <ul class="l2">
      <li>
        <a href="#" title="">Menu</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" title="">Quem sou?</a>
        <li>
          <a href='#' title=''>Categorias</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#' title='Sub Produto 1'>Sub Produto 1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' title='Sub Produto 2'>Sub Produto 2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' title='Sub Produto 3'>Sub Produto 3</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' title='Sub Produto 1'>Sub Produto 4</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' title='Sub Produto 2'>Sub Produto 5</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' title='Sub Produto 3'>Sub Produto 6</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' title='Sub Produto 1'>Sub Produto 7</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' title='Sub Produto 2'>Sub Produto 8</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' title='Sub Produto 3'>Sub Produto 9</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' title='Sub Produto 1'>Sub Produto 10</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' title='Sub Produto 2'>Sub Produto 11</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' title='Sub Produto 3'>Sub Produto 12</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" title="">Contato</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" title="">Anuncie</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Como eu faço agora para que ele só apareça quando eu passar o mouse?

Me desculpe se eu não expliquei direito!

Comment: Veja [**este link**](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/ddownmenu.php). Ensina em 2 partes como fazer um menu como você quer. Já implementei esse menu em projetos passados e funcionou perfeitamente, basta ler atentamente as instruções.

Comment: Você tem preferencia por ser puro css/html ou js?

Comment: Obrigada @DiegoFelipe esse link me ajudou a entender o que queria.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade Tanto faz, eu queria apenas entender o que fazia isso acontecer.. Mas consegui, obrigada!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O display:none esconde o submenu e o display:block faz ele aparecer... 
Coloquei o seguinte código no css, e deu certo. 
Obs.: As respostas ai em cima, estão certas.. Mas aqui está como eu coloquei no meu menu.

```
/*Escondendo o submenu*/
header li ul {
position: absolute;
display: none;
background-color: #ECECEC;
}
/*Estilo do submenu, e também fazendo-o aparecer.*/
header li ul a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #777;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bom, como você esta utilizando um HTML e CSS de exemplo, você poderia utilizar esse HTML e CSS e editar da melhor forma que você desejar, segue os códigos:

```html
<div class="menu-container">
    <ul class="menu clearfix">
        <li><a href="#">Bruto</a>
            <!-- Nível 1 -->
            <!-- submenu -->
            <ul class="sub-menu clearfix">
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a>
                    <!-- Nível 2 -->
                    <!-- submenu do submenu -->
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Sub</a>
                            <!-- Nível 3 -->
                            <!-- submenu do submenu do submenu -->
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Sub</a></li>
                            </ul><!-- submenu do submenu do submenu -->
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Sub</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Sub</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Sub</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Sub</a></li>
                    </ul><!-- submenu do submenu -->
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            </ul><!-- submenu -->
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

E Segue o CSS:

```css
body, 
.menu,
.sub-menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.clearfix:after{
    content: '.';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.menu,
.sub-menu {
    list-style: none;
    background: #000;
}
.sub-menu {
    background: #444;
}
.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.menu li {
    position: relative;
}
.menu > li {
    float: left;
}
.menu > li:hover {
    background: #444;
}
.menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 150px;
}
.sub-menu li:hover {
    background: #555;
}
.sub-menu .sub-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
```

Encontrei esses códigos no seguinte link:

https://www.todoespacoonline.com/w/2014/10/menu-html-com-css-com-submenu-e-subniveis/

Fiz o teste e funciona normalmente.

Até.

Comment: Tinha visto esse post tbm.. Mas como ele já estava pronto e o meu também estava pronto, ai ficou um pouco complicado saber o que deveria mudar exatamente. vllw mesmo assim.

Answer (score 1):

Apenas acrescente essas duas classes em seu CSS:

```
/* SUBMENU */
header nav ul li > ul{ /* esse último "ul" seria o submenu */
  display: none;
}

header nav ul li:hover > ul{
   display: block;
}
```

A primeira esconde seu SubMenu quando entra no site.

E a segunda abre o SubMenu quando passa o mouse sobre o LINK principal. Note o uso do `hover`.

Comment: Sim, está correto. Eu tinha visto no site que me enviaram.. Fiz uma adaptação para o meu e consegui entender, vllw.